# How to build configurable facade over set of RESTful services

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee

It's time to ask question on StackOverflow because I did not find a good one in Google.

We have a legacy systems(2 in my case) that provide some functionality via RESTful web-services.
Now we are building a Java EE system that will consume RESTful services from that legacy systems.

Questiuon: how to build convenient facade API over mentioned RESTful web-services to use them easily in our Java EE app?
Are there some frameworks to easily consume a set of REST web-services and it can be XML-configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a number of options

1. The most "low level" - HTTP Client (http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/)
2. Something more abstract - RestEasy ClientRequest/ClientRespons (http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.2.GA/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/client/ClientRequest.html) there is a number of tutorials how to work with it
3. You might like it most due to XML config - Spring Framework RestTemplate support (see, for instance http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html), there is a number of tutorials in the web too.